# Slow winforms rendering when using MDI?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, rendering, mdi

I'm doing a small project in C# and Windows.Forms where it makes sense to use a multi-document interface. The problem is that windows placed inside the MDI-parent are really really slow to render. It almost looks like hardware accelerated drawing gets turned off for those windows.  The effect is especially visible when moving them over each other, re-sizing and scrolling lists.  The noticeable exception is the embedded WebBrowser control, which at least scrolls very smoothly.

If I turn off MDI, and show my windows without the MdiParent set, they render as quickly as other apps.

Is this normal behaviour, and is there a way to avoid the slowdown?

All help is appreciated (:

Comment: could be anything perhaps  you are doing something incorrectly.. could be some issues with your logic.. could be `Parent / Owner` issues in regards to how you are doing your assignments etc.. Show your code will be your best option here in regards to relevant code and the issue at hand...

Comment: do you have user controls? use double buffering. i found an issue that the mdiclient control doesn't inherit double buffering correctly. maybe you have to set it manually with reflection. google found some vb snippets, they are not c#.

Comment: I would recommend first using the Profiler (in the Analyze menu) and trying to figure out where your CPU cycles are going. That may show up that a single method / control redraw is running very slowly under MDI. If your MDI forms are extremely complicated, sometimes it's faster when you move the form to take a screenshot, override redraw, and just display that until you drop it again. MDI is quite slow and sometimes acts strangely too, so good luck!!

Comment: Well, somehow this fixed itself, or through some of my fiddling I triggered something that made the problem go away /:  I honestly have no idea what the solution was.  I suspect perhaps double buffer drawing was set as false somewhere, and is now in the right state.

In any case, the problem was not with the child windows, as they would render just fine when I displayed them as top level windows or embedded them in TabPanels.  Something good came from this experimentation though: I have implemented switchable window modes in my app ;)

Thanks for all your suggestions!